# Interactive markup does not work/ javascript is ignored by superset

Tags: apache-superset

I am looking to create some dynamic buttons and dropdown menu's using HTML/markup in markup Visualization of Apache Superset. I can only create static HTML pages, as the JavaScript associated with it is not working. Is it possible to add plugin like R, idyll for interactive markup in superset or is there a way to make the JavaScript working?

[image: Attached is the image of the static markup]

Answer (score 0):

for simple visuals, you can customize the CSS. To add Javascript you'll have to write a custom visualization plugin and add it to the respective dashboard.
https://superset.apache.org/docs/contributing/creating-viz-plugins/